# How can I synchronize a production meteor js database with development?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, data-synchronization

I'm just getting into Meteor, and am similarly new to MongoDB.  I am accustomed to syncing MySQL dbs (production vs dev) for running tests of new features with near-live data.  At present, I don't know how to do this with meteor.

From this (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteormongo) I gather that I can use a mongoDB shell to work with my local db, but from looking at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/, I haven't yet figured out if this is the path I should be following to sync things up for Meteor.

Has anyone set up a relatively straightforward procedure for syncing Meteor JS db's, or can you point me to resources that might help me get up to speed?

Comment: To clarify, I am primarily interested in moving data between different copies of the database (between live/production and dev for example).  Secondarily, if there are any handy GUI's or ideas on semi-automation strategies, that would be useful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understood the question, but:

1. You can choose the db you are working with by setting the `MONGO_URL` environment variable
2. You can [dump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/) the data from one db and load it to another (if this is what you want to do)

Comment: For #1, you are suggesting that I can work on my localhost, but configure it to use the live/remote app's db?  That could be useful in some cases...

Comment: And yes, something like #2 is more what I'm looking for.  From your link, I understand that I would be using mongoexport on the source, and mongoimport on the target, correct?  And I could do this all from running 'meteor mongo' to get a mongodb shell, and use the MONGO_URL env variable to switch between source and target?

Comment: If you don't use Meteor's local db you don't even have to use `meteor mongo` just connect with `mongo` to the appropriate server (may be local). Unless of course you prefer to use the meteor local db for testing.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of interesting ways to do this.

The first method that I have thought about using was by using replicas.

You would have a development server database; by this I mean an entire server dedicated to housing a development database (say a cloud instance on AWS). Once you wish to replace that development instance you would simply take one member out of your live set and start it up as a stand-alone instance replacing your development instance.

Anohter method is to just copy the `mongod` directory to somewhere and start up a `mongod`. The simplest method but maybe not the best, especially if you have a large distributed database.

Another method is to use `mongodump` to dump the data out of the database and the restore it onto your development machine.

The last two are very common methods, the first one is kind of one I have been thinking about in my head for a while.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a quick script for downloading a Production Meteor DB. [meteor-download](https://github.com/AlexeyMK/meteor-download).  Easy as `./download.sh origin.meteor.com`

It doesn't provide 2-way sync yet, but that shouldn't be too much of a chance if you feel up to it.

Answer (score 2):

## Check out [mongo-sync](https://github.com/sheharyarn/mongo-sync)

---

It's a script I wrote for my self when I had to constantly copy my Local `MongoDB` database to and from my Production DB for a Project (I know it's stupid).

Once you put your DB details in `config.yml`, you can start syncing using two simple commands:

```sh
./mongo-sync push       # Push DB to Remote
./mongo-sync pull       # Pull DB to Local
```

*If you use it inside some project, it's a good idea to add `config.yml` to `.gitignore`*

---

[image: mongo-sync demo gif]