# Update documents from server to local in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two mongodbs, one is on my server and another is on my laptop.

how do I sync from server to local once a day? What is python code to do it?

Comment: This post might be of some assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670762/synchronize-mongo-databases-on-different-servers

Comment: If not that, then just export and import with a cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `mongodump` from the server to your laptop and then run `mongorestore` on your laptop to sync the data. How frequently you want to do this depends on how big your dataset is and if you have the bandwidth for it. You could try the following steps and see if they work for you.

**To backup:**

From your laptop's Terminal, assuming you have Linux or Mac OSX, run the following commands (the Windows commands are very similar):

```
$ mongodump --host <HOST> --authenticationDatabase admin -u <USER> --password <PW>
```

If you don't have authentication set up, then you can omit the authentication and credentials information. So the command would look something like this:

```
$ mongodump --host <HOST>
```

**To restore:**

This will create a `dump` folder in your current directory containing the backup. Then when you want to restore you would run the following. You can omit the `--drop` flag if you don't want to drop the databases before restoring.

```
$ mongorestore --drop
```

Try these commands and if they work for you, you can write up a shell script which you can run daily in order to sync your database. Also, if your dataset is big enough and you want to be super precise about syncing your data, you can run the `mongodump` with the `--oplog` option. This means that the dump will include a partial oplog containing operations from the duration of the mongodump operation. Then to restore you run `mongorestore` with the `--oplogReplay` flag. This will ensure that any operations that occurred during the dump will also be backed up.

For more information, you should check out the [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore) pages in the documentation.